# How to open a netlogo model from the community?

Tags: netlogo

I am getting "unable to open model with current format" when trying to run two netlogo models from community. The models are:

- http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/community/Reinforcement%20Learning%20Wargame

and

- http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netels/models/community/Reinforcement%20Learning%20Maze

I think it is happening because I am trying to run the models in netlogo 6.1.0 while they were written in an older version, but I also don't know how to find out in which version they were written.

How can I run these community models?

Comment: I think your diagnosis is correct. You can see the contents of a NetLogo model with any text editor. For the problem of opening them in NetLogo, you can use the date submitted to the community models to work out the software version that was current at the time. Old versions of NetLogo are downloadable from the Netlogo website.

Comment: Both those models are for NetLogo 3, you can see the version in the files if you download them and open them in a regular text editor.  The usual advice to get them to run in the latest NetLogo is to upgrade to 4.1.3, then to 5.3.1, then to 6.1.0.  If you're very familiar with the NetLogo language and file format, it might be easier to manually update the models yourself, but in general I'd recommend using the old versions.

Answer (score 2):

[This utility](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alan-isaac/econpy/master/abm/netlogo/netlogo4to6.py) may prove useful.

1. Install Python 3.12. (Accept installation of the py launcher.)
2. Download netlogo4to6.py to wherever you want to be using it (e.g., a `temp` folder).
3. From your preferred shell (e.g., PowerShell), enter
   `py -3.12 netlogo4to6.py mypath`
   where `mypath` is the path to the file you wish to convert.

Comment: How or where do i run that code?